# Importing Data and Schema to MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to learn SQL and I downloaded a database to practice. I downloaded two files of extension .sql, one is the schema and the other one the actual data. I've also installed MySQL Workbench. I've been googling and I've been trying things to solve this but I don't understand Workbench and I can't load the database.

Where do I import the schema and the data in order to try queries ?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is simple in Workbench, and I'll use the freely available sakila database as an example. Feel free to apply this to your situation:

1. Download "sakila" from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html
2. Extract it somewhere, in my case, onto the Desktop into a new sakila-db/ directory
3. Open Workbench
4. In the Schema Navigator, right-click an empty area and choose "Create Schema"
5. In the schema creation wizard, name it "sakila", keep the defaults, hit "Apply", finish wizard
6. Go to "File" -> "Run SQL Script..."
7. Choose "sakila-schema.sql", make sure "Default Schema Name" is blank or select "sakila", execute
8. Go to "File" -> "Run SQL Script..."
9. Choose "sakila-data.sql", execute
10. Click the "refresh" icon in the Workbench Schema Navigator (or restart Workbench)
11. Now, use the populated sakila database :)

Steps (4) and (5) are optional in this case (as executing sakila-schema.sql creates the schema), but the idea is worth mentioning.

Here's how it would look when loading th script into the SQL IDE:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the way the task should be done in MySQL Workbench. Just an additional note: instead of using "Run SQL Script" you could just load the script into an SQL editor and run it from there. When loading the sakila data file you will be asked for it's enconding - choose Latin1.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is from 4 years ago, so I thought I'd give an update as in MySQL Workbench 6.3 the procedure is a bit different.

You have to select the menu item *Server -> Data Import -> Import from Self-Contained File* and select the SQL file containing the database you want to import.

In *Default Target Schema*, select the database you want to import the SQL dump to, or create a new empty database via *New...*

Then click on *Start Import*.

Comment: Is there a bug in Workbench 8.0? The list is empty and I can't create the schema because it already exists.

Comment: I simply used sed an all the files exported by the workbench:
`sed -i 's/Database: oldname/Database: newname/' *`

Answer (score 0):

You could use mysql console from terminal. Login through the user id and pass. Then create a Database from the following command is the .sql file does not have one such command to create so.

```
Create database db-name
use db-name;
SOURCE xyz.sql;
```

Source command would load the the content from xyz.sql to your database created. This would be reflected later in workbench indeed.

Comment: Thanks !. And how is the schema loaded ?

Comment: It would be the same way.. Nothing changes.. Just login and source your schema.sql file.

Comment: Thanks. I tried those commands but I can't still not see any database in Workbench, or if there is one I don't know where to look.

Comment: what does your schema.sql file contains? if im not wrong it would contain queries to create database and create table. can show query once "show databases" and check if the database is created?

Comment: -1, the question is about doing it in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy on Linux platform just follow below mentioned steps, After downloading zip file of sakila-db, extract it. Now you will have two files, one is ***sakila-schema.sql* and other one is *sakila-data.sql***.

---

1. Open terminal
2. Enter command ***mysql -u root -p < sakila-schema.sql***
3. Enter command ***mysql -u root -p < sakila-data.sql***
4. Now enter command ***mysql -u root -p*** and enter your password, now you have entered into mysql system with *default* database.
5. To use sakila database, use this command ***use sakila;***
6. To see tables in sakila-db, use  ***show tables*** command

---

Please take care that *extracted files are present in home directory* else provide the absolute path of these files in all above commands.