# How do I install the Sakila database into MySQL Workbench on a Mac?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

How would I go about installing the Sakila database onto my Mac?

[Importing Data and Schema to MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260235/importing-data-and-schema-to-mysql-workbench)

I've used the comment by user dr01 in this post, but I'm not sure if I'm ready to use it or not. The Sakila file I downloaded has 3 files (sakila-data.sql, sakila-schema.sql,sakila.mwb) but I only used the schema file while importing it into Workbench. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Pretty simple: the Sakila DB is so small you can just run the 2 SQL files in Workbench:

- Download the sakila dump from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html.
- Open a connection to your server in MySQL Workbench, where you want to load Sakila.
- In the SQL editor toolbar there's a button to load a file. Click that and select `sakila-schema.sql`.
- Once loaded you just execute the full editor content. This is for the DB structure.
- Now load the content by opening the `sakila-data.sql` script. Again, execute the entire editor.

Now refresh the schema tree by clicking on the small refresh icon

[image]

and you should see the Sakila schema in the tree. That's it.

Comment: thank you so much. This is really useful.
I completed the setup in just 2 mins 

Answer (score 1):

Have two options for installing Sakila (where its sakila-schema.sql, sakila-data.sql or sakila-mwb)

**First one**
Go to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html and then to "Example Databases" and then to "Sakila Database" and download
[(Example image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liGQ7.png)

**Second one**
Re-run your MySQL installer and add "Samples and Examples"
[(Example image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzBJV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the installer again, choose -> Documentation/Samples and Examples and your done